# Arithmetic mean of $n$ terms in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence of numbers $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$, such that $a_1=0,|a_n|=|a_{n-1}+1|$, where $n$ is greater than or equal to $2$. Prove that the Arithmetic mean of the $n$ numbers ($a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n$) is not less than $\frac{-1}{2}$. Does this question require many cases(for the absolute function)? Am I missing something? It looks a difficult problem, otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like it's just an exercise to get you used to proofs.  That absolute value is probably just there to confuse you, or to make the proof really trivial -- depending on what the question allows you to assume.

Comment: It looks to me like $a_n = n$.

Comment: How can you say that?

Comment: By induction. For $n=1
 $ we have $$a_{1}=a_{0}+1=1.
 $$ Now assume that $a_{n-1}=n-1
 $. Then $$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+1=n.
 $$

Comment: Seems to me, I made a few typos... Please see again.

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. Absolute value produces a positive value.
2. Positive values are closed under addition.
3. All numbers less than -1/2 are negative.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this works for any value of $a_0$ as long as $n > 1$.

Consider a two-term sequence. If $a_0 < 0$, then $a_1 = |a_0 + 1| = -1 - a_0$. In this case, the arithmetic mean is $(-1 - a_0 + a_0)/2 = -1/2$.

If there are more than two terms, the later terms ($a_3, a_4, \dots$) will all be positive and will increase the arithmetic mean. Therefore, $-1/2$ is the minimum possible value of the mean.

Comment: please see the question again.